# Error on create choice field

Tags: mysql, django

i'm creating a choice field but dont show my dropdown on the template:

my model:

```
Inactive = 0
Active = 1

state_choices = (
    (Inactive, 'Inactive'),
    (Active, 'Active')
)
class Tipe(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=state_choices,
        default=Active,
    )

class People(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=state_choices,
        default=Active,
    )
    tipe = models.ForeignKey(Tipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**the forms.py:**

```
class PeopleForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    name.widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control', 'required': 'true' })


    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=9)
    phone.widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control', 'minlength':'9'})

    optionState = (('1', 'Active'),('0', 'Inactive'),)
    state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=optionState )
    state.widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control', 'required':'true'})

    tipe = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tipe.objects.filter(state=1), widget=forms.Select)
```

**this return on my template for type:**

```
<select id="id_tipe" name="tipe">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">Tipe object</option>
<option value="3">Tipe object</option>
</select>
```

dont show values on my dropdown only show Tipe object dont names of tipes models. please any suggest.. thanks !!

Comment: I find it rather strange that you define numbers as choices, but then store these in a `CharField`.

Comment: Furthermore your problem description is quite confusing. If you want it to show for example the `.name` you probably should override the `__str__` function.

Comment: yeah, is only dont show the names of tipes models..only show...Tipe object

Comment: well define the `__str__` function at the `Tipe` model, and let it return `self.name`.

Comment: oh thanks im goiing to try

Comment: thanks @WillemVanOnsem you solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you never specified *how* a `Tipe` object should get printed, so Python/Django falls back on the default string representation of such models. Typically that is `'Tipe model (123)'` with `123` the primary key of the object.

By overriding the `__str__` function, you can define a custom way to present your objects. For example you can use the `.name` attribute like:

```
class Tipe(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=state_choices,
        default=Active,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can of course define something more sophisticated if you want, the point is that you define a way to represent the objects in dropdowns and other instances where you show an object in a template.

Although this has nothing to do with the problem, I would advice you to use `IntegerField`s for your `state` fields, since `0` is an integer, and not a character (or string), and thus is closer to the type of values you use to represent the state.

Comment: thanks soo mucho by your suggest and answer i change my model to IntegerField dont Charfield